# Text align doesn't center and middle itself when using a border-radius

Tags: html, css

I need to align the no. 1 to the center of the red circle, but it is not working

```
#box {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    color: #FFFFFF;

    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kFaXp/8/

How would I get 1 to center in the middle of this box.​

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Text-align centre only centre horizontally. you can try this

```
#box {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    color: #FFFFFF;

    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell

}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kFaXp/14/

Comment: for this method text always comes in middle no matter whatever your div height

Answer (score 8):

Add `line-height: 50px;` to the CSS for the element.

```
#box {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/kFaXp/9/

Comment: So should line-height be the same as width and height of the div which has border-radius.

Comment: It should generally be the same as the height of the div :)

Comment: But when height increase we have to update line-height also. rather than we should display table cell property

Comment: Yes, if it's a dynamic div then table cell would work better. But seeing as the OP asked just for a static div, this solution works.

Answer (score 2):

you can achive your desired results by defining `line-height: 50px;`

http://tinkerbin.com/I2slDWGY

Answer (score 0):

By adding line-height and vertical-align property

```
#box {
 background: red;
 border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
 color: #FFFFFF;

 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 vertical-align:middle;
} ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kFaXp/13/

Comment: vertical align middle does nothing when using line-height in this case

Comment: @Mike: yes you are right, we have to use display table cell if we are using vertical-align:middle